# Apply "autoindex on;" only at root of folder and index documents at following subfolders

Tags: nginx

What I'd like is to apply `autoindex on;` only at the very root folder and afterwards (as soon as the user selects a folder) use the traditional "index.php" files if available and as defined in `index index.html index.htm...` etc. I don't know the number of folders inside the root neither their names. How can this be done, given these restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a regular expression location that will match any URI below the root, for example `./`

This block should be placed below the `location ~ \.php$` (or similar) so that PHP scripts continue to be handled correctly. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
}
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
location ~ ./ {
    index index.php;
}
```